# gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3> django project

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

gunicorn status

```
gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-03-12 18:30:15 UTC;
Process: 3535 ExecStart=/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollageenv/bin/
Main PID: 3535 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[3535]:   File "/home/mike/mo
Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[3535]:     time.sleep(0.1)
Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[3535]:   File "/home/mike/mo
Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[3535]:     self.reap_workers
Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[3535]:   File "/home/mike/mo
Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[3535]:     raise HaltServer( 
Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[3535]: gunicorn.errors.HaltS
Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main pr
Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit en
Mar 12 18:30:15 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed
29 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed
```

nginx error log:

```
2018/03/12 04:59:08 [error] 1562#1562: *1787 connect() to unix:/home/mik
e/movingcollage/movingcollage.sock failed (111: Connection refused) whil
e connecting to upstream, client: 107.205.110.154, server: movingcollage
.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/mike/movin
gcollage/movingcollage.sock:/", host: "movingcollage.com"
```

My config is ok, this used to work; I pulled some new application code and am now getting a 502 bad gateway error (before I pulled the application code the site worked fine). I already did `service gunicorn restart` and `systemctl restart gunicorn` and am still getting the 502 bad gateway error. Can anyone help?

This is a django project, for what it's worth.

Gunicorn config:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling movingcollage"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/mike/movingcollage

exec movingcollageenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollage.sock movingcollage.wsgi:application
```

gunicorn --bind=unix:/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollage.sock movingcollage.wsgi.application

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01:/etc/init# gunicorn --bind=unix:/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollage.sock movingcollage.wsgi:application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
 line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", li
ne 185, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", li
ne 71, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", lin
e 169, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", lin
e 477, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", lin
e 542, in spawn_workers
    time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", lin
e 209, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", lin
e 459, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Comment: there is no useful information here. get at least the rest of the lines containing `gunicorn[3535]`

Comment: @hop I added lines from `gunicorn --bind=unix:/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollage.sock movingcollage.wsgi.application` which is the same as that in gunicorn[3535] (the lines had cut off and i couldn't paste them)

Answer (score 0):

Running `gunicorn --bind=unix:/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollage.sock movingcollage.wsgi:application --preload --loglevel=debug` and leaving it running worked after solving import errors